# Validacion Javascript no permite enviar el formulario

Tags: javascript, php, html

estoy intentando hacer un formulario de contacto con validación en Javascript. La cuestión es que cuando se verifica el campo y doy clic en el botón Enviar no hace nada, espero alguien pueda ayudarme, no sé si hace falta agregar o quitar elementos.

Adjunto mi código.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="assets/css/validation.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <form action="#" id="signup" class="form" method="post">
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="nombreCompleto">Nombre Completo:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombreCompleto" id="nombreCompleto" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Nombre">
            <small></small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="assets/js/validation-paquetes.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Creo que el error se encuentra en esta parte, pero no logro saber qué es lo que falta.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

let isnombreCompletoValid = checknombreCompleto();

let isFormValid = isnombreCompletoValid;

if (isFormValid) {
    
    form.submit();
}
});
```

Comment: Debes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar la función `checknombreCompleto`